# Error while running code through TestNg

Tags: java, selenium

Getting configuration error while running the below code. Due to which i am unable to do further actions. Could someone please help me to run script.

========================================================================
      package Flipkart;

```
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

    public class report {
        WebDriver driver;
      @Test
      public void f() throws InterruptedException {

          driver.get("https://www.coopathome.ch/de/");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wa-badge']/span")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mastheadMyAccountLink']/span")).click();
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("tinamalhotra325@gmail.com");
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("google@123");
            driver.findElement(By.id("loginOverlaySubmitLoginFormButton")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ul/li[7]/a/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnav--item-m_0222']/li[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ul/li[7]/a/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnav--item-m_0222']/li[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[3]/div/div/div[4]/button")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/button[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnav--item-m_0001']/li[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
    //      WebElement apple_price=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/button"));
    //      if (apple_price.getText().equals("3.80"))
    //      {
    //          System.out.println("price matched");
    //          
    //          } 
    //      else {
    //          System.out.println("title not matched expected title is "+ apple_price.getText()); 
    //      }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnav--item-m_0055']/li[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[5]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("miniCartProceedToCheckoutButton")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("miniCartProceedToCheckoutButton")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='heimlieferung']/div[4]/dl/dd[2]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("chooseDeliveryDate_continue_button")).click();
            WebElement t=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/dd"));
            if (t.getText().equals("120.40"))
            {
                System.out.println("price matched");

                } 
            else {
                System.out.println("title not matched expected title is "+ t.getText()); 
            }
    //      String Total_Cart=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/dd")).getText();
    //      System.out.println(Total_Cart);
    //      if
    //      Assert.assertEquals(Total_Cart, 120);
    //      System.out.println("Test case passed");


      }
      @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

          Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
          prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
          options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      }

      @AfterMethod
      public void afterMethod() {
          driver.close();
      }
```

## }

```
Error:
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\SalunkheP\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1281031724\testng-customsuite.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 18277
Only local connections are allowed.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Flipkart.report.afterMethod(report.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:703)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

FAILED: f
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Flipkart.report.f(report.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@649d209a: 81 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 54 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6fffcba5: 70 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3ab39c39: 149 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@16c0663d: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@ea4a92b: 5 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake.

**WebDriver driver;** is a class variable i.e any method of the class can use it.

In @BeforeMethod, you have written a line:
**WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);**. Please replace it with 
**driver = new ChromeDriver(options);**

You are creating a separate object of type Webdriver, the value for the class variable driver is still "null", hence you are getting Null Pointer exception.

Comment: How is your Answer different from @vijayjawale Answer? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. The answer is not different. When I started writing an answer, it wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

In your beforeMethod you have local variable `driver` in this line:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It must be as:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Method will be as below:

```
 @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
          prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
          options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      }
```